# Count specific ordered pairs of cells in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am looking to check 1 column for the number of times we get SomeValue in a cell and SomeOtherValue in another cell, say 2 below.

For example, if I have SomeValue = COW, SomeOtherValue = CHICKEN and the below column:

```
CHICKEN
COW <-
DOG
CHICKEN <-
CAT
DOG
CHICKEN
DOG
COW
CHICKEN
COW
CAT
CAT
DOG
DOG
COW
CHICKEN
CAT
DOG
COW  <-
COW
CHICKEN <-
```

I will count 2 instances of COW with CHICKEN 2 cells later.

I have been trying with COUNTIFS but can't seem to get it to check the value of one row against another row defined relative to the first.  I think this should be possible with COUNTIFS but I can't figure it out.  I am confident that I could calculate this with a VBA script but I would prefer a formula that live updates as I change the cell contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With countifs the ranges must be the same size.  So, use two ranges the same size offset by 2 rows:

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A20,"COW",A3:A22,"CHICKEN")
```

[image]

Comment: This works for me and it is way nicer to look at than some of the nonsense I had! Thank you! :D